# Unable to Build in Jenkins with Maven Build Profile

Tags: maven, jenkins, build, pom.xml

I am trying to build a maven project in Jenkins with Build Profile ID of `pom.xml`. But Jenkins is only building with dev profile and not catching any of other profiles. with the same `pom.xml`.

I've tried building on command prompt and it's working fine, I just cannot do it in Jenkins.

Comment: Why do you need profiles to build your project?

Comment: Hi thanks for reply.. we are using build profiles for pipeline deployment on different environments, we have centrailzed pom.xml file which is used by developers also. The same code need to deployed on SIT/UAT/Preprod/Live..

Comment: Which is not a task for Maven it's more a task for Jenkins..so you should build the appropriate artifacts for each environment or having a single artifact which is deployed to the appropriate environments and enriching the deployment with the appropriate configuration for the environments..The question is also what are the differences between the environments?

Comment: Well I've created a new Branch in SVN which is not accessible to Developers and changed the the name of Project Object Module Name from pom_updated.xml to pom.xml... renaming the pom worked for me.. may be it's silly but that i required renamed pom.

Answer (score 1):

I am having similar issue running maven 3.3.9 from Jenkins ver. 2.138.
So far, with time consuming trial and error, I have found that Jenkins does not tolerate a space between the -P and the profile name AND it can only handle a single profile.  So you should be able to get something like this to work:

mvn groupId:artifactId:goal -Pprofile-1-only

Answer (score 0):

how did you set-up your Jenkins to run the command?

Profiles should b specified using the -P option:

```
mvn groupId:artifactId:goal -P profile-1,profile-2
```

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

My guess is that in your Jenkins config (build steps), you have not specified anything, or you provide the wrong profile.

Could you try and let us know?

Comment: I've provided profile as (clean install -Psit) and pom.xml in Build Step of Maven project. the sit profile is available in pom.xml, I've tried with this but it was not working and only catching dev profile

Comment: What command do you use in your Jenkins to build your application? It sounds like your maven setting are good, but your Jenkins setting might be missing an option.